# Taking samples from summarized data

Tags: r, aggregate, resampling

I have data in a form much like the output from `aggregate`, except that I do not have the original non-aggregated data.

Example:

```
 data <- data.frame(grade=letters[1:4], count=c(3,9,4,1))
  grade count
1     a     3
2     b     9
3     c     4
4     d     1
```

I would like to sample from this population of grades, e.g. using `sample`. What is the easiest way of taking a sample (without replacement) from summarized counts like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you expect something like this?

```
> sample(with(data, rep(as.character(grade), count)), 10)
 [1] "b" "b" "d" "a" "c" "c" "b" "b" "c" "b"
```